# How to use Swagger in Quarkus with Ingress-Ngnix Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, swagger-ui, quarkus, nginx-ingress

Good Afternoon. I'm trying to use Swagger in Quarkus and locally it works great for me, however when I upload it to the production environment I'm using Ingress-Nginx as a reverse proxy in a Kubernetes cluster and I'm running into a problem, I don't allows you to view the Swagger interface:

Postman Local:

[image]

Swaager Local:

[image]

Postman Kubernetes Environment with Ingress-Nginx:

[image]

Swaager-Ui in Kubernetes Environment with Ingress-Nginx:

[image]

My application.properties:

```
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=oracle
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
#quarkus.datasource.jdbc.driver=io.opentracing.contrib.jdbc.TracingDriver
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxxxxxxxxxx:1522/IVR
quarkus.datasource.username=${USERNAME_CONNECTION_BD:xxxxxxxx}
quarkus.datasource.password=${PASSWORD_CONNECTION_BD:xxxxxxxx.}
quarkus.http.port=${PORT:8082}
quarkus.http.ssl-port=${PORT-SSl:8083}


# Send output to a trace.log file under the /tmp directory
quarkus.log.file.path=/tmp/trace.log
quarkus.log.console.format=%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%c{2.}] (%t) %s%e%n
# Configure a named handler that logs to console
quarkus.log.handler.console."STRUCTURED_LOGGING".format=%e%n
# Configure a named handler that logs to file
quarkus.log.handler.file."STRUCTURED_LOGGING_FILE".enable=true
quarkus.log.handler.file."STRUCTURED_LOGGING_FILE".format=%e%n
# Configure the category and link the two named handlers to it
quarkus.log.category."io.quarkus.category".level=INFO
quarkus.log.category."io.quarkus.category".handlers=STRUCTURED_LOGGING,STRUCTURED_LOGGING_FILE

quarkus.ssl.native=true

quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.key-store-file=${UBICATION_CERTIFICATE_SSL:srvdevrma1.jks}
quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.key-store-file-type=${TYPE_CERTIFICATE_SSL:JKS}
quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.key-store-password=${PASSWORD_CERTIFICATE_SSL:xxxxxxx}
quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.key-store-key-alias=${ALIAS_CERTIFICATE_SSL:xxxxxxxxx}
quarkus.native.add-all-charsets=true
quarkus.swagger-ui.path=/api/FindPukCodeBS/swagger-ui
quarkus.smallrye-openapi.path=/api/FindPukCodeBS/swagger

mp.openapi.extensions.smallrye.info.title=FindPukCodeBS
%dev.mp.openapi.extensions.smallrye.info.title=FindPukCodeBS
%test.mp.openapi.extensions.smallrye.info.title=FindPukCodeBS
mp.openapi.extensions.smallrye.info.version=1.0.1
mp.openapi.extensions.smallrye.info.description=Servicio que consulta el codigo puk asociado a una ICCID (SIMCARD)
mp.openapi.extensions.smallrye.info.termsOfService=Your terms here
mp.openapi.extensions.smallrye.info.contact.email=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com
mp.openapi.extensions.smallrye.info.contact.name=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@telefonica.com
mp.openapi.extensions.smallrye.info.contact.url=http://exampleurl.com/contact
mp.openapi.extensions.smallrye.info.license.name=Apache 2.0
mp.openapi.extensions.smallrye.info.license.url=https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html
```

What can be done in these cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Swagger-UI is included by default only in dev mode.

To enable it on your application, you must set this parameter:

```
quarkus.swagger-ui.always-include=true
```

This parameter is build time, so you can't change it on your deploy. You must set it into your `application.properties`.

### Reference

https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config#quarkus-swagger-ui_quarkus-swagger-ui-swagger-ui

[image]